# SetTimer() pitfalls

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a windowless timer (no WM_TIMER) which fires a callback function only once when a given time period is elapsed. It is implemented as a `SetTimer()/KillTimer()`. Time periods are small enough: 100-300 milliseconds.

Is that cheap enough (I mean performance) to call `SetTimer()/KillTimer()` pair for every such short time interval?

What if I have 100 such timers which periodically call `SetTimer()/KillTimer()`? How much Window timer objects may exist simultaneously in the system?

That is the question:
Use a bunch of such timer objects and rely on good Windows implementation of timers, or create one Windows timer object that ticks every, say, 30 milliseconds, and subscribe all custom 100-300 milliseconds one-time timers to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with timer messages as you are trying to use them is that they are low priority messages. Actually they are fake messages. Timers are associated with an underlying kernel timer object - when the message loop detects the kernel timer is signalled it simply marks the current threads message queue with a flag indicating that the next call to GetMessage - WHEN THERE ARE NO OTHER MESSAGES TO PROCESS - should synthesise a WM_TIMER message just in time and return it.

With potentially lots of timer objects, its not at all obvious that the system will fairly signal timer messages for all the timers equally, and any system load can entirely prevent the generation of WM_TIMER messages for long periods of time.

If you are in control of the message loop, you could use maintain your own list of timer events (along with GetTickCount timestamps when they should occur) and [MSGWaitForMultipleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(v=vs.85).aspx) - instead of GetMessage to wait for messages. Use the dwTimeout parameter to provide the smallest interval - from now - until the next timer should be signalled. So it will return from waiting for messages each time you have a timer to process.

And/Or you could use [waitable timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx) - either on a GUI thread with MSGWaitForMultipleObjects, or just on a worker thread, to access the lower level timing functionality directly.

Comment: I do not use WM_TIMER. I use windowless timer (pass time proc pointer directly to ::SetTimer()). The question is about how it is expensive to create/destroy timer kernel objects intensively and how much such objects may exist simultaneously without any problem. Thanks.

Comment: You are always using the WM_TIMER. GetMessage synthesizes the message, and DispatchMessage - when passed a WM_TIMER message with a NULL hwnd, dispatches it directly to the TimerProc/LPARAM.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "when the message loop detects the fire".  The way it works is that a system thread manages the full list of user timers and does the fire detection and sets the flags to wake the right thread.  GetMessage will see the flag and, if no other messages exist, have to go and actually dig for that timer.  The only thing the thread knows is 1) a timer fired and 2) how many fired.  GetMessage has to actually make a call to scan the entire user timer list and find the earliest one associated with your thread.  Your next GetMessage finds the next one and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pitfall is that actually it is **USER object** (despite the fact it's not listed in [MSDN USER objects list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4)) hence it falls under Windows USER objects limitation - by default max 10000 objects per process, max 65535 objects per session (all running processes).

This can be easily proven by simple test - just call [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (parameters don't care, both windowed and windowless act the same way) and see USER objects count increased in Task Manager.

Also see ReactOS [ntuser.h](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/win32ss/include/ntuser.h?view=markup) source and [this article](http://volatility-labs.blogspot.ru/2012/09/movp-33-analyzing-user-handles-and.html). Both of them state that `TYPE_TIMER` is one of USER handle types.

So beware - creating a bunch of timers could exhaust your system resources and make your process crash or even entire system unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details that I feel you're actually after while asking this question:

SetTimer() will first scan the non-kernel timer list (doubly linked list) to see if the timer ID already exists.  If the timer exists, it will simply be reset.  If not, an HMAllocObject call occurs and creates space for the structure.  The timer struct will then be populated and linked to the head of the list.

This will be the total overhead for creating each your 100 timers.  That's exactly what the routine does, save for checking against the min and max dwElapsed parameters.

As far as timer expiration goes, the timer list is scanned at (approximately) the duration of the smallest timer duration seen during the last timer list scan.  (Actually, what really happens is -- a kernel timer is set to the duration of the smallest user timer found, and this kernel timer wakes up the thread that does the checking for user timer expirations and wakes the respective threads via setting a flag in their message queue status.)

For each timer in the list, the current delta between the last time (in ms) the timer list was scanned and the current time (in ms) is decremented from each timer in the list.  When one is due (<= 0 remaining), it's flagged as "ready" in its own struct and and a pointer to the thread info is read from the timer struct and used to wake the respective thread by setting the thread's QS_TIMER flag.  It then increments your message queue's CurrentTimersReady counter.  That's all timer expiration does.  No actual messages are posted.

When your main message pump calls GetMessage(), when no other messages are available, GetMessage() checks for QS_TIMER in your thread's wake bits, and if set -- generates a WM_TIMER message by **scanning the full user timer list** for the smallest timer in the list flagged READY and that is associated with your thread id.  It then decrements your thread CurrentTimersReady count, and if 0, clears the timer wake bit.  Your next call to GetMessage() will cause the same thing to occur until all timers are exhausted.

One shot timers stay instantiated.  When they expire, they're flagged as WAITING.  The next call to SetTimer() with the same timer ID will simply update and re-activate the original.  Both one shot and periodic timers reset themselves and only die with KillTimer or when your thread or window are destroyed.

The Windows implementation is very basic, and I think it'd be trivial for you to write a more performant implementation.